# Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_0^x\cos\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I can't use l'Hôpital because $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\cos\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ doesn't exist. I tried to use sandwich theorem 
$$
\frac{\int_0^x\cos\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt}{x}\leq \frac{\int_0^xdt}{x}\leq1
$$
but I didn't find a good lower bound.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite
$$\int_0^x\cos\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt = \int_0^x\bigg(-{t^3 \over 2}\bigg)\bigg({-{2 \over t^3}}\cos\frac{1}{t^{2}}\bigg)dt$$
Now integrate this by parts, intgerating ${-{2 \over t^3}}\cos\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ and differentiating $-{t^3 \over 2}$. You get
$$-{x^3 \over 2}\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}} + \int_0^x{3t^2 \over 2} \sin\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt$$
By bounding $|\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}}|, |\sin\frac{1}{t^{2}}| \leq 1$, you get that this expression is of absolute value at most ${5 x^3 \over 6}$. So dividing by $x$ and taking the limit as $x$ goes to zero will give zero.

Comment: OTOH, by MVT, there's a $x_0\in\{0,x\}$ much that $$\int_0^x\cos(1/t^2)dt=(x-0)\cdot\cos(1/x_0^2),$$ hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_0^x\cos\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt}{x}=\cos(1/x_0^2).$$  Doesn't that mean that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No it just means $x_0$ will be such that $\cos({1 \over x_0^2})$ is very nearly zero, and will get closer and closer to zero as $x$ approaches $0$. (Recall that $x_0$ is a function of $x$ here.)

Comment: Now I strongly doubt that $\cos(1/x_0^2)$ will be close to zero as it is heavily oscillating.

Comment: It's sort of counterintuitive, but $x_0$ will not decrease continuously to zero as $x$ goes to zero. There's no oscillation here.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: perhaps you are aware that given any number $k\in[-1,1]$ there exists a sequence $x_n$ with $x_n\to 0$ and $\cos(1/x_n^2)\to k$.